# Avoid repaint canvas when scrolling

Tags: java, canvas, swt

I followed this [tutorial](http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_Tutorial/SWT/Canvas#Canvas:_scroll_an_image_.28flicker_free.2C_no_double_buffering.29), in order to display some graphical element on a canvas:
Here is where I come:
**Scroll listener**

```
vBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                System.out.println("Scroll event");
                int vSelection = vBar.getSelection();
                int destY = -vSelection - origin.y;
                canvas.scroll(0, destY, 0, 0, canvas.getSize().x, canvas.getSize().y, false);
                origin.y = -vSelection;
            }
        });
```

**Resize listener**

```
canvas.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                System.out.println("Resize event");
                Rectangle client = canvas.getClientArea();
                vBar.setThumb(Math.min(theoreticalScreenHeight, client.height));
                vBar.setPageIncrement(Math.min(theoreticalScreenHeight, client.height));
                vBar.setIncrement(20);
                int vPage = canvas.getSize().y - client.height;
                int vSelection = vBar.getSelection();
                if (vSelection >= vPage) {
                    if (vPage <= 0)
                        vSelection = 0;
                    origin.y = -vSelection;
                }
            }
        });
```

**Paint listener**

```
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Paint event");
                // Costly drawing here
                ...
                // rectangle
                for (int productIndex = 0; productIndex < products.size(); productIndex++) {
                    Product p = products.get(productIndex);
                    ...
                    e.gc.drawRoundRectangle(rectEdge.x, rectEdge.y, (int) productWidth, productHeight, 30, 30);
                    Point prevSubRectEdge = rectEdge; // Coordinate of each result rectangle
                    for (int resultIndex = 0; resultIndex < productResultsAmount; resultIndex++) {
                        Result result1 = p.getResult(resultIndex);
                        ...
                        e.gc.drawLine(sepStart.x, sepStart.y, sepEnd.x, sepEnd.y);
                        ...
                    }
                    rectEdge.y += 300;
                }
                drawLinks(e);
            }
         });
```

Since I display a lot of graphical element, it can take some time to be displayed. That is why I would like to display them once at the beginning, and because there is a lot, I would like to scroll vertically on the canvas, so I can see all of my elements.

My problem here is that the scroll event trigger the repaint event, which is redrawing the elements. But since it's a costly operation, it is not the thing that I want.

I would like to avoid this repainting behavior, and just paint the elements once in the beginning, and then simply scroll to see them.

I have added the code, because I thought somebody would like to see it, but I don't think it is really helpfull, it was just to show the difference between the [tutorial](http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_Tutorial/SWT/Canvas#Canvas:_scroll_an_image_.28flicker_free.2C_no_double_buffering.29) and my code. I think it is more a matter of swt comprehension, about listener and repainting life cycle ?
I also have to say that I never call `canvas.redraw()`.

Here is a screenshot of my canvas:
[image]

Comment: This isn't possible. You could draw everything in to an Image and then just draw the image. The paint event will have a clipping rectangle which you can use to check if drawing particular parts of the canvas is required.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am not sure how to draw a part of an image. It should be something like this :`gc.drawImage(cache, 0, origin.y, screenSize.x, screenSize.y, 0, 0, screenSize.x, screenSize.y);` (with `origin.y` the place where I scrolled vertically).But it is not working, as I am getting an error `Argument not valid`

Comment: Well, it was my bad. It is actually working, by doing this : `e.gc.drawImage(cache, origin.x, origin.y);` with `origin.y` which is the point for the vertical scroll.
Thank you!